# Keybindings, specifically using the Super key in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: settings, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to use IntelliJ Idea for some Kotlin development, and coming from Mac, I wanted to use the Mac key bindings. They rely fairly heavily on the Super key as an alternative to the Command key on Mac, and I find that IntelliJ is entirely unable to pick up `Super+anything` keybindings.

That is to say, if I wanted to, say, undo something, the "Macish"  keybinding is set to `Super+z`, and if I actually press that combination, it just prints a `z` to the screen. Similarly, if I want to quit a tab, I try `Super+w` and it just prints a `w` to the screen.

I tried disabling virtually all the keyboard keybindings in the Elementary OS Keyboard Settings menu that use the Super key. It still seems that the modifier is not reaching the app.

Any ideas on how I might be able to fix this behavior? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is lame but most of linux distros comes with prebuilt keybindings for people who quits windows, so... that explains your problem.

Have you tried using CNTRL key instead of SUPER ?
if that doesn't work you should read [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html).
And change the keymaps for your use.

Another solution is to change the keymap of the system for Mac support, maybe the kernel doesnt configure that well, have you checked that? Let me know

**UPDATE**

So i investigate more and found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368437/how-do-i-remap-my-ubuntu-keyboard-shortcuts-to-match-osx) method if not try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235533/how-to-set-keyboard-layout-for-a-macbook-pro) other one.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Renato. I can change the shortcuts, and use Ctrl if I need to, but I'm coming from Mac, so I would really like to use (for example) `Meta + R` = Run tests, or `Meta + Shift + R` = run tests under cursor. The "default" linux key bindings are `Shift + F10` and `Ctrl + Shift + F10` for those respectively and I'm not the biggest fan, they require me to reach much further on the keyboard.

Comment: @NikhilGajwani please check out the new links