# Jetbrains IDE not receiving "Super" / meta key input

Tags: settings, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to use PHPStorm and set up some keybindings using the super / meta key ("windows" key on my keyboard) but it looks like PHPStorm is not receiving the keyboard input at all (e.g. when I try to define a new keyboard shortcut, it won't pick up any combination when I start with the super key).

A similar problem is outlined in [Keybindings, specifically using the Super key in IntelliJ Idea](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/12247/keybindings-specifically-using-the-super-key-in-intellij-idea) however there is not really a satisfactory solution, as I would like to keep all other functionality involving the super key such as `⌘ - space` to bring up the Elementary launcher, which would break if I were to remap the key entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I use PhpStorm on a Mac (iMac), and on Linux (laptop), day in, day out, and so feel your pain of having to change shortcuts depending on which computer I'm at.

However, because the Super key on Linux is very much for handling window/desktop operations rather than app specific operations, and is in a different position on my keyboard compared to the Apple key, I've decided not to use the Super key for app stuff.

A lot of the PhpStorm shortcuts are the same across the default Windows (Linux) and macOS setups. This includes things like Alt-F12 for toggling the built in terminal, or Alt-9 for Version Control panel etc.

But otherwise, a lot of operations switch to Ctrl instead of Apple key, and I don't find that too hard to remember after a minute or two of switching computers, what with the keyboard being different layout too.

I've also just the other day installed the "Key Promoter X" plugin in PhpStorm, originally to try and get me to use shortcuts more often, but it really helps in discovering the differences too through it's balloon pop-ups and panel I can check.

Sorry I don't have technical "solution" here, but hopefully it still helps a little, even if it's just moral support from another dealing with the same issue!